# Are there any conventions on how to treat throw-away parameters

Tags: java, java-8

Suppose I have a situation like this:

```java
map.compute(key, (k, v) -> {
    // Only do stuff with v.
});
```

Since I only work with `v`, I don't need the first parameter `k`. Some languages allow `_` which is—in my opinion—a neat way to visualize that there's a throw-away parameter.

Unfortunately, `_` is a reserved keyword in Java (8). Are there any conventions or best practices how this is done with Java?

Comment: No. Don't try using `_` in Java (even though that's a valid identifier name). In Java 9, the use of `_` as an identifier name is most likely [going to be forbidden](https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/underscore_is_a_keyword_in).

Comment: Underscore is reserved for lambda parameter names.